# .class:hover not happening

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have two classes with the following code-

```
<div class="arrow-left"> <h1> < </h1> </div>
<div class="arrow-right"><h1> > </h1> </div>
```

Their style -

```
.arrow-left{
position: fixed;
top:40%;
left:10%;
vertical-align: middle;
height:80%;width:5%;
text-align: center;
}
.arrow-right{
position: fixed;
top:40%;
right:10%;
vertical-align: middle;
height:80%;width:5%;
text-align: center;
}
.arrow-left:hover, .arrow-right:hover{
background-color: #4EB30B;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

They are used for navigational purposes.
When I hover over the .arrow-left, it's background doesn't change, but the .arrow-right one's background changes when I hover over it.
And once I've clicked on .arrow-right , and I hover over over .arrow-left, it's background changes!
This is happening in Chrome on Ubuntu.

Here is the [webpage](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/115036486/main.html)
I want to know why this happens but no workaround needed.

Comment: You should html-escape the arrows: `>`=>`&gt;`, `<`=>`&lt;`. See if it works then.

Comment: no,escaping isn't working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is caused by the positioning of the arrows, in your example-link the left-arrow hover is working when mouse is about 150px below the left arrow, you should give it a width and height in px so the hover acts only when you are really hovering the box

additional, the `div.b-wrap` is over the left arrow box use the property `z-index`

Comment: But, why is it that when i have clicked the right arrow, the left arrow starts accepting :hover? Does the book's z-index decrease?

Comment: i was absent, but i see, you got it ! looks nice

Answer (score 1):

Add `z-index:100` to `.arrow-left`

Comment: `z-index:1` will do; no need to crank it up.

Comment: @JanDvorak z-index:1 didnt do that

Comment: @Morpheus try adding it in his website and check it